# ActiveRecord joins rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Job, Category and JobCategory models in my rails application. I am using postgresql as the database. I have many-to-many relationship between my Job and Category models. On my Job show page along with the job currently being shown I want to display all the jobs which belongs to the same category that of currently being shown job.i have achieved this by using this query.

```
@similar_jobs = Job.joins(:job_categories).where("category_id in (?)", @job.category_ids)
```

but problem with this query is that along with those jobs displayed, i am also getting the job listed which is being currently shown . I want to exclude that job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it for you...

```
@similar_jobs = Job.joins(:job_categories).where("category_id in (?) AND job_id != ?", @job.category_ids, @job.id)
```